# 'sqrt' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, math, std, sqrt

I compile my program in Linux - it has the following line:

```
std::sqrt((double)num);
```

On Windows, it is ok. However, on Linux, I get an error:

> `sqrt` is not a member of `std`

I have already included `math.h`.

What is the problem with that?

Comment: Did you include `<cmath>`?

Comment: `#include <cmath>`, according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt

Comment: I observed the same difference on Windows and Linux

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change the directive to `#include <cmath>`. C++ headers of the form `<cxxxxxxx>` are guaranteed to have the standard names in `std` namespace (and may optionaly provide them in global namespace). `<xxxxxx.h>` are not.

Comment: `guaranteed to have the standard names in std namespace` before `c++11`. Of course the reason that was relaxed for 11 was that some implementations never bothered.

Comment: @BoBTFish It is still guaranteed to have the standard names in `std` namespace.  Pre C++11, it was also guaranteed _not_ to have them in the global namespace.  C++11 allows them to also be in global namespace, since this was the most widespread existing practice.

Comment: @BoBTFish What JamesKanze said, see 17.6.1.2/4.

Comment: Yup, sorry about that, I posted before I went looking for confirmation. I won't delete it, that'd just make the subsequent comments confusing.

Answer (score 6):

it is simply because `<math.h>` does not declare the functions in `namespace std`. It has been included into the C++ standard only for compatibility reasons. The correct C++ include would be `<cmath>`.

**§D.5,2**

> Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding `cname` header is placed within the global namespace scope. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared or defined within namespace scope of the namespace `std` and are then injected into the global namespace scope by explicit *using-declarations*.

That your code worked under windows was pure luck - if you want to call it so. The last sentence gives a hint what might happen under windows, but not under linux: under windows, obviously the names are valid in both the global namespace and namespace `std`.

Comment: `<math.h>` is part of standard C, as a "compatibilty feature".  There are, in fact, good reasons to prefer it, at least in certain cases.  Of course, it declares `::sqrt`, and not `std::sqrt`.

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks for the correction, I wasn't aware of that. I changed my answer.