# CMake: ‘sqrtf’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++11, cmake

After compiling my program with

```
$ cmake .
$ make
```

I get 5 errors of this form:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target Project
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/myproj.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /path/to/my/proj/main.cpp:2:0: 
/path/to/my/proj/library.hpp: In member function ‘virtual double MyProjClass::get_value(double, double) const’:
/path/to/my/proj/library.hpp:419:26: error: ‘sqrtf’ is not a member of ‘std’
     const float F = (std::sqrtf(1.0f + 2.0f) - 1.0f) / 2;
                      ^
```

Other errors include `floorf` not being a member of `std`.

Looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518210/sqrt-is-not-a-member-of-std), it's because I'm not compiling with C++11, and looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake) thread, "[...] CMake will make sure the C++ compiler is invoked with the appropriate command line flags."

Well, my CMake is obviously not doing this. Why am I getting these errors, and how do I go about fixing them?

Edit: Here's my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Noise)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp vector.hpp noise.hpp)
add_executable(Noise ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(Noise ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: The problem is either in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, or in your C++ code. You haven't shown either, so we cannot help.

Comment: Why use `sqrtf` or `floorf`? Especially with c++11, `sqrt` is able to handle `float`s directly.

Comment: @Angew Added CMakeLists.txt

oLen: Your comment solved this. Replacing all instances of floorf and sqrtf with floor and sqrt removed the errors. No idea why.

Comment: And the reproducing code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't say what C++ compiler you are using but assuming it is g++ 5.x though 7, `sqrtf`
and `floorf` are not within the `std` namespace under `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++1z`. They are
simply in the global namespace, when `cmath` is included.

Comment: That makes the standard library in question non-conforming. All C standard library names are supposed to be placed in `::std` when the `<c:::>` headers are used.

Comment: Agree. `<cmath>` must put them in `std::` and may also put them in the global namespace; `<math.h>` is the other way around.